# How to change the font size of Excel file exported from a Datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to change the exported Excel file's default font size of `11` to `9`. This is my excel button.

```
{
  extend: 'excel',
  filename: 'filename',    
  customize: function( xlsx) {
    var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml']; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to get in your file the data file which is `sheet1.xml` but the one you're looking to modify is the `styles.xml` containing the font.

First things first, you'd need to extend `excelHtml5` as customization doesn't work on `excel`.

Afterwards you can change the font-size this way :

```
customize: function(xlsx) {
    var sheet = xlsx.xl['styles.xml'];
    var tagName = sheet.getElementsByTagName('sz');
    for (i = 0; i < tagName.length; i++) {
      tagName[i].setAttribute("val", "22")
    }
  }
```

The `sz` corresponds to [this](https://github.com/DataTables/Buttons/blob/7e4247adb688f7dd5b6695e71b2d6c8f806cc7a4/js/buttons.html5.js#L577) which is the part you'd want to change in the styles file.

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/k9pjaomw/